# Latest time to eat the first Shabbat meal

Tags: halacha, shabbat, zemanim, meal-seudah, orach-chaim

What does the Halacha specify about the latest permissible time to eat the first Shabbat Seudat? Can it be eaten past midnight or no?

Comment: It is not clear that there are times for the Shabbos meals. The Rambam holds that there are but Tosfos, the Tur and the Shulchan Aruch seem to hold that there are not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch Harav [271:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.16?lang=bi) says the seuda time lasts all night:

> אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁמִּצְוָה מִן הַמֻּבְחָר לְקַדֵּשׁ סָמוּךְ לִכְנִיסַת הַשַּׁבָּת, מִכָּל מָקוֹם נִמְשָׁךְ עִקַּר מִצְוָתוֹ כָּל הַלַּיְלָה